# Grails web app generates MySql Duplicate entry for remote DB but not for local test DB

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Hosted server: 
 Tomcat 7, MySql 5.5.24

Local server:
 Tomcat 7, MySql 5.6

Grails 2.4.2

The issue only occurs when using the hosted database, not my local MySql server.

**The error occurs in the following code.**

```
@Override
    def save()
    {
        def comment = new Comment(request.JSON)
        def place = Place.get(params.placeId)
        place.addToComments(comment)
        place.save(flush: true) //Explodes here

        respond comment
    }
```

**The error is**

```
| Error 2014-08-13 18:19:01,678 [http-bio-8086-exec-5] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_fojv2ahcp1jompc2cg2gryqce'
| Error 2014-08-13 18:19:01,789 [http-bio-8086-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException occurred when processing request: [POST] /SecondAmendmentSupporters/places/1/comments/
Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_fojv2ahcp1jompc2cg2gryqce'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_fojv2ahcp1jompc2cg2gryqce'
    Line | Method
->>  411 | handleNewInstance  in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    386 | getInstance        in     ''
|   1041 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|   4237 | checkErrorPacket   in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   4169 | checkErrorPacket . in     ''
|   2617 | sendCommand        in     ''
|   2778 | sqlQueryDirect . . in     ''
|   2834 | execSQL            in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2156 | executeInternal .  in com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement
|   2441 | executeUpdate      in     ''
|   2366 | executeUpdate . .  in     ''
|   2350 | executeUpdate      in     ''
|     39 | save . . . . . . . in secondamendmentsupporters.CommentController
|    198 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    895 | runTask            in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    918 | run . . . . . . .  in     ''
^    695 | run                in java.lang.Thread
```

The association between Place and Comment is a many to one.  Many comments to one place.

If you look at the request below, it looks as if the database is trying to add a new entry to the DB for the Place with ID 1 versus just updating it.

> [POST] /SecondAmendmentSupporters/places/1/comments/

The only difference between the remote DB and the local DB is the MySql version.  Could this be the problem?

**EDIT**

Place Domain

```
static hasMany =
    [
        comments:Comment
    ]
```

Comment Domain

```
static belongsTo = [place: Place]
```

**EDIT**

Turns out that grails is treating my foreign key place_id as an Index(MUL) locally but on my remote DB, it’s Unique(UNI) thus causing the duplicate id exception.  Thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many many hours, I was able to determine the difference between my local db and my remote db.  Turns out that GORM set my foreign key 'place_id' as UNI instead of a MUL.  I dropped my table in the remote DB and added the following mapping to my comment domain and problem solved.

`static mapping = {place index: 'place_id'}`

Answer (score 0):

Yo are saving place object instead of the comment object. Put

```
comment.save(flush:true)
```

instead of

```
place.save(flush: true)
```

and try again

Comment: Thought of that and no good.  Same error.  Also, this only happens from my hosted MySql DB, not my local MySql DB.  Thank you though.

Comment: Try then with `place.save(flush:true, update:false);` I really don't know what could be the problem.
Check schema of both databases if there is something different. Maybe the schema's are not the same

Comment: No good either.  It's strange.  I compared my schema for both DBs and they are the same with the exception of column ordering.  This just makes no sense.

Comment: I Edited my question to include the relationship definitions between place and comment.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this, think I have the same issue, but can't figure out why, and I have no relationship, it is a table I just write too. More details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357521/duplicate-entry-issue-for-grails-on-non-primary

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Or at least I found the answer to my one, think you have the same one. 
Open the database (via mysql workbench and table inspector or similar), and what had happened was that something had created an index against a column. I say something, because there was nothing in the grails code or domain that had created this index, but for whatever reason the index would not allow multiple entires. Once the index was deleted it all worked for me.