# Duplicate entry issue for grails on non primary

Tags: mysql, grails

Decided to add a little log that basically logs a code, the request ip and a date stamp.

This is the domain class

```
  class Requestlog {
    String countryiso
    Date requestdate
    String requestaddr
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

And the code that creates the record

```
    def reqip = request.remoteAddr
    def reqdate = new Date()
    def reqrec = new Requestlog(countryiso: countryiso, requestaddr: reqip, requestdate: reqdate )
    reqrec.save(flush:true,failOnError:true)
```

But if the same code from same IP is requested twice (at different times)

```
Duplicate entry 'GL' for key 'UK_3noxnln23h2w0wtormncmk2a1'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Duplicate entry 'GL' for key 'UK_3noxnln23h2w0wtormncmk2a1'
    Line | Method
```

The thing is, I am not setting any of the columns to be unique. And looking at the database schema, there is no constraints other than that the id column auto increments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling about for a while I found the issue.

The reference to the key 'UK_3noxnln23h2w0wtormncmk2a1' is the key (no pun attended). 
This is an index which seems to be auto generated by either grails or mysql at creation, so as soon as I tried to create a new entry with the same code in the database, it threw an exception because it requires that only one entry matches the index.

I went in via mysql workbench editor and deleted it, and my app started working (and is still working hopefully)

Would be interesting to know if it is mysql or grails that sets the index, and if there are functions that will not work now. For me I am only writing to this table, never reading, so the index makes little difference to me.

Please note that if you have create on datasource.config you will have to delete the index every time you start your application (and don't delete the one called ID, its the one with the long name you want).